# How is it possible to change RGB color filter panel to BGR color filter panel if the color filter is physically firmly mounted on the LCD display?

Tags: lcd, tft, pixels

How is it possible to change RGB color filter panel to BGR color filter panel if the color filter is physically firmly mounted on the LCD display?

[TFT display design.](https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/powerhouse/posts/display-power-why-does-tft-lcd-needs-temperature-compensation)
[image]
Are RGB colors created only by the display color filter?
Without a color filter, do all three sections of the pixel have the same color (white or gray, depending on the polarization intensity of the polarizing layer)?

Displays have the ability to change the RGB color filter panel to the BGR color filter panel.

[Example from ILI9341 Display Datasheet.](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/ILI9341.pdf)

The BGR bit of the Memory Access Control register controls whether the color filter will be, RGB or BGR.

[image]

**How is it possible to change RGB color filter panel to BGR color filter panel if the color filter is physically firmly mounted on the LCD display?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a datasheet for a display, it's a datasheet for a display driver chip. You have to tell it what type of display is connected to the chip.

If you tell it the wrong resolution or color order it doesn't cause the display to grow more or different pixels, you just get a corrupted image.

If you remove the color filters you'd have a grayscale image.

Answer (score 1):

The driver cannot change how the panel works.

If the panel was rotated (for example, a cell phone rotated 90 or 180 degrees) then the RGB/BGR bit order will change in order to display the same image to the viewer.

Other scanning sequences must alsobe changed ans shown in [the image](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/ILI9341.pdf) on page 127.

[image]

This is how a device can be rotated, while the image is not.